# Android TextView text alignment

Tags: android, textview

I don't know how text is going to be aligned in advance. But I will be getting horizontal and vertical alignment separately. What is the best way to set the alignment programmatically. I can do something like this:

```
/**
 * Sets text alignment
 * @param alignment
 */
public void setAlignment(String alignment, String vAlignment){
    if (alignment.equals("Left")){
        if (vAlignment.equals("Top"))
            setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP);
        else if (vAlignment.equals("Center"))
            setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER);
        else if (vAlignment.equals("Bottom"))
            setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.BOTTOM);
    }
    //same for other horizontal alignments
```

Is there any other way of doing this? I will also have to look at text justification and stretching later on, so it would be easier if I could have horizontal and vertical alignments set separately one after another. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the operator `|=`. It behaves exactly like `+=`, and it is suitable for `int` values.

```
    public void setAlignment(String alignment, String vAlignment){

            int myGravity = 0;
            if (alignment.equals("Left")){
                    myGravity |= Gravity.LEFT;
            }

            if (vAlignment.equals("Top")){
                    myGravity |= Gravity.TOP;
            }

            ...

            myTextView.setGravity(myGravity);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of aligning text view is something like this.

```
            LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lp.addRule(LinearLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
            textView.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

setGravity is also a correct way of Aligning!!

You can ask if you have any further queries

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving horizontal and vertical alignment in string, and after compare it. give this method int values and only one line to set the. like.

```
public void setAlignment(int alignment, String vAlignment){
    if (vAlignment==48)    // vAlignment will be 48=top, 17=center, 80=bottom
        setGravity(alignment | Gravity.TOP);
    else if (vAlignment==17)
        setGravity(alignment | Gravity.CENTER);
    else if (vAlignment==80)
        setGravity(alignment | Gravity.BOTTOM);
}
```

Or you can also use string as vAllinment, which you is already using.

Another Way

```
    public void setAlignment(int alignment, String vAlignment){
    if (vAlignment==Gravity.TOP)    
        setGravity(alignment | Gravity.TOP);
    else if (vAlignment==Gravity.CENTER)
        setGravity(alignment | Gravity.CENTER);
    else if (vAlignment== Gravity.BOTTOM)
        setGravity(alignment | Gravity.BOTTOM);
}
```

Comment: You're using the operator `==` to compare a String to an int, and that should never be done. Does that really work?

Comment: Sorry for that, For comparison use "equals" if string and use "==" if int.

Comment: That's OK, but `vAlignment` is a String and `Gravity.TOP` is an int. Not sure about what you want to do. Are you suggesting passing vAlignment as `"48"`, for example?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but both parameters are passed as String. It is possible to pass it as integer, but it seems like the other answer is more suitable as I won't need to make any changes to data.