# Programmatically set text alignment in a TextView

Tags: java, android, textview

In my app, I have a button that creates a TextView with a certain message. How can I set the text alignment of the text to the right of the TextView? I see the attribute in XML, but I don't know how to do it in java.

Comment: Which textview? awt? swing? javafx?

Comment: This kind: TextView tv = new TextView(MyActivity.this);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right align text in android TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8969122/right-align-text-in-android-textview)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android TextView text alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217834/android-textview-text-alignment)

Answer (score 7):

Try using

```
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

You can set textview's gravity using

```
textLabel.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin you can use something like the below,

```
 val textView = TextView(context)
 textView.apply {
     layoutParams = TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)
     textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_VIEW_START
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is what worked for me (in kotlin):

```
textView.textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) Make sure the width is not set to wrap_content

2.) If the text view is inside another container, set gravity to the container. Remember that gravity is to align text and stuff like that while layout_gravity is used to align views within a parent.

3.) TextAlign aligns text at the beginning, end, left, or right of the container. Gravity is a bit more flexible with Center_Vertical, Center_Horizontal, or Center.

Answer (score 0):

textView.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);